# Translate a MySQL query into Knex equivalent syntax?

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I'm having a hard time replicating a specific MySQL query into Knex (I am using Bookshelf as the ORM). The SQL query returns all tables' metadata from the database.

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT
    T.TABLE_NAME,
    C.COLUMN_NAME,
    C.COLUMN_TYPE,
    N.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
    K.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,
    K.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
  FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
    LEFT JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C USING (TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME)
    LEFT JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE K USING (TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME , COLUMN_NAME)
    LEFT JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS N USING (TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME , CONSTRAINT_NAME)
  WHERE
    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'sakila'
    ORDER BY T.TABLE_NAME
```

This query returns the relation between each table of the database and details about the schema of each table. I don't know the correct way to proceed this with knex.

I tried writing the query with knex, but INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS are somethings which are very particular to MySQL client however my use case requires me to use it even for MS SQL. And there is not much documentation on INFORMATION_SCHEMA usage for knex.

Grateful for any insights - many thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? see the examples in https://knexjs.org/

Comment: I tried but there is not much documentation for INFORMATION_SCHEMA usage for knex.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
knex('TABLES as T')
  .withSchema('INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
  .select(
    'T.TABLE_NAME', 
    'C.COLUMN_NAME', 
    'C.COLUMN_TYPE',
    'N.CONSTRAINT_TYPE',
    'K.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME',
    'K.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME'
  )
  .join('COLUMNS as C', 
    builder => builder
     .on('T.TABLE_SCHEMA', 'C.TABLE_SCHEMA')
     .on('T.TABLE_NAME', 'C.TABLE_NAME')
  )
  ... rest of joins ...
  .where('TABLE_TYPE', 'BASE TABLE')
  .where('TABLE_SCHEMA','sakila')
  .orderBy('T.TABLE_NAME')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the other joins have INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS which are very particular to MySQL client however my use case requires me to use it even for MS SQL. So is there some knex equivalent solution for it?

Comment: I might not have understood your problem, but If you mean those `JOIN ... USING (TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME , COLUMN_NAME)` style of joins, you can see from my example how to convert them to `JOIN ON` clauses. I don't see how building those other joins differs from the first one.

Comment: Problem is REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME are not accessible in MSSQL so this query will throw an error. I just wanted to know if there was a knex alternative to it.

Comment: No there is not. Knex usually does not abstract away DB differences (except for very limited extent). You need to figure out how to do that query in mssql too.